# Invoking HTTP post endpoint with the certificate in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest

Can anyone help me how to invoke the secure HTTP endpoint with the certificate which is in **sample.crt** format .I'm using Rest Template in Spring boot and it is throwing SSL handshake Exception .Below is my syntax.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sample/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createProducts(@RequestBody List list) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<List> entity = new HttpEntity<List>(list,headers);

        return restTemplate.exchange(
                "https://localhost:8080/sample", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class).getBody();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use RedirectView class for redirecting to https site, either localhost or on direct online web.

```
@RequestMapping("/to-be-redirected")
public RedirectView localRedirect() {
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView.setUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
    return redirectView;
}
```